# Dynamically sort table using tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have table like this which i want to sort by clicking header of table.
I am following this tutorial 
http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/27/make-html-table-sortable-jquery-tablesorter-plugin

This is working fine for manually added data to table but for dynamically added by angular it is not working.

```
<table class="table table-bordered tablesorter"  id="myDummyTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>Birth Date</th>
            <th>Join date</th>      
            <th>Marks 1</th>
            <th>Marks 2</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class = "smaller">
        <tr ng-repeat="show in showdata">
            <td>{{ show.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ show.age }}</td>
            <td>{{ show.birthdate}}</td>
            <td>{{ show.joindate}}</td>
            <td>{{ show.mark1  }}</td>
            <td>{{ show.mark2 }}</td>

           </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any other way to do this or I am doing it wrong?

Comment: You can use AngularJS Tablesort. Visit this link: https://github.com/mattiash/angular-tablesort to refer more. Hope to help, my friend.

Comment: Hi @Tomato32, Thanks , It is working perfectly.

Comment: Well played, my friend :D

Answer (score 0):

This Might help you.
Call `$("table").tablesorter();` after appending data to the table DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#myDummyTable").tablesorter();
 });
```

Comment: can you explain it more? I am not from this background.

Comment: @AyushGoyal ,  **table sorter** plugin has the method called `tablesorter()` and when you need to bind the `table sort` you have to  call the method `tablesorter()` to expose the sorting functionality